# How to add auto-slide to wordpress slider?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slideshow

anyone of you knows how I can add auto-slide to my wordpress slider? Here is the link of the website: http://taratur.com/2013/

The slider currently is not sliding automatically, so, I wanted to set timer to it so change it's slides. If any other info needed, please let me know...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me which slider you have used here, give me the name of slide so i will check it on my site then i will tell you the fix of it.

Comment: On the templates is used iosslide... I hope now you have vision where exactly I have to edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a timer by using the setInterval() method.

var autoanimate = setInterval('rotate()', 1000);

The times calls the rotate() function after 1000 miliseconds :)